# Jinja - Using a different css for each extended template

Tags: flask, jinja2

I've come across Flask-Appbuilder as it could solve my problem. I'm trying to load different css for every template where only the skeleton remains the same.

I found this solution https://flask-appbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/templates.html

However it doesn't work. Not for me anyways. I used `pip3 install flask-appbuilder` and everything went OK. I created appbuilder directory within templates directory. Then I used:

```
{% extends 'appbuilder/base.html' %}

{% block head_css %}
    {{ super() }}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="url_for('static',filename='css/your_css_file.css')}}">
{% endblock %}
```

what might be causing the problem ? It's like the `block head_css` is being completely ignored. Only the basic bootstrap css is being loaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have a single `layout.html` file extended by all templates, then use `if` statements to select the correct CSS style sheet for each template by accessing `request.endpoint` which is basically the view function that renders a template.

```
{% if request.endpoint == 'index' %}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% elif request.endpoint == 'another' %}
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', filename='another.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Is this answer missing an `{% endif %}`?

Comment: @AmbassadorKosh Yes. I've added it.